# How to output an error in a chat system if a spam condition is detected?

Tags: php, sql, ajax, chat

I have a chat system and I if a user sends more than 3 messages in a row I want to display an error. I want to build a mini anti-spam feature.

My PHP script:

```
         if ($naaa > 3) {
         echo "error";
        } else { 
$sql = "INSERT INTO messages (user,message,textcolor,date) VALUES (:sas,:asas,:asafs,$time_limit)";
        $q = $db->prepare($sql);
        $q->execute(array(':sas'=>$user,':asas'=>$message,':asafs'=>$text));

        echo '<div style="color:'.$text.'">'.$user .' : '. $message.'</div>';
        }
```

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: how i can do if user send more than 3 message he have a error.

Answer (score 0):

You'll write a query that selects all messages in the past `x` minutes, depending on how you want to rate limit. If the number of matching rows is 3, display an error and don't accept the message.

#### Reply to comment regarding times stored as seconds:

It's important to know what those numbers mean - first of all, their unit is the second. Second of all, they represent the number of seconds that has elapsed since an arbitrary time known as the Unix Epoch. Therefore, to get `thing`s from the past 3 minutes:

```
$oneMinute = 60; // 60 seconds in a minute
$threshold = $oneMinute * 3; // we want three minutes to be our cutoff
$compareTime = time() - $threshold; // messages since 3 seconds ago

$query = "SELECT COUNT(1) FROM `messages` WHERE `sent` > $compareTime;";
```

That query will return a single row whose value is the number of matching rows.

Comment: i want do or X minutes or 3 rows. you can give me a code like past X minutes?

Comment: the time in my database is in numbers .. like : 1397679661

Comment: Edited my answer. Let me know if anything's unclear.

Answer (score -1):

Something like this might help

```
<?php
session_start();
// Check if we stored the last message sent date to session
$lastTime = ( isset( $_SESSION["lastTime"] ) ) ? (int)$_SESSION["lastTime"] : false;
// Check if we stored the number of times user sent messages in a row
$hasError = ( isset( $_SESSION["hasError"] ) ) ? (int)$_SESSION["hasError"] : 0;

// if we got the last message sent time
if ( $lastTime ) {
  $difference = ( time() - $lastTime );
  if ( $difference < 10 ) { // 10 seconds
    // increase the number of messages user sent in a row
    $_SESSION["hasError"] = $hasError = ( $hasError + 1 );
  }
  else {
    // else reset the counter to 0
    $_SESSION["hasError"] = $hasError = 0;
  }
}

// if user trying to send more that 3 messages in a row
if ( $hasError > 3 ) {
  // show the error
  echo "error";
}
else {
  // save the last sent time
  $_SESSION["lastTime"] = time();

  // insert message to db
  $sql  = "INSERT INTO messages( user, message, textcolor, date ) VALUES( :sas, :asas, :asafs, $time_limit )";
  $q    = $db->prepare ($sql );
  $q->execute( array( ':sas' => $user, ':asas' => $message, ':asafs' => $text ) );
  echo '<div style="color:'.$text.'">'.$user .' : '. $message.'</div>';
}
?>
```

Comment: i dont understand .. :( i need to do a select from the database i need something like that: 

if (time() - $query3 > 1800) {

}

Comment: This is easily circumvented by clearing cookies. A better way is to check a trustworthy source - the server. Checking for messages in the database/message queue can't be spoofed.

Comment: @Jeff study the difference between `$_SESSION` and `$_COOKIE`

Comment: So if you want to use db instead of session, then store the time and counter into database.

Comment: The reason, Why i used session instead of database is that he wants to display an error, if user tries to send more than ***3 messages in a row***. Querying db everytime is a bad idea.